# I can not find windows portable devices in php

Tags: php, filepath

I want to browse my digital camera by php codes, to transfer pictures from camera to my server, but I can't find true location of pictures.

when i use

```
is_dir('C:\My Piictures\000012.jpg')
```

its work good.

But when I use

```
is_dir('Computer\D90\Removable storage\DCIM\100NCD90\DSC_0007.JPG')
```

Its not working

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Did you try using the drive letter?

Comment: use the drive letter your camera gets the moment you plug it in(d:,e:,f:,g:,h:,i:,j:,etc...)
PHP needs an absolute path.

Comment: It is portable device, not have any drive letter

Comment: Do you see any icon in 'My Computer' when you connect your camera ? If yes, what is its name?

Comment: The name is D90
(under Protable Devices category)
my device is Nikon digital camera D90

Answer (score 0):

You can't access media deivce in PHP in Windows (In Linux that is not a problem).

You should copy your files to a hard drive, or connect your camera as Removable Media, not a media device and assign a drive letter (for example `E:`).

After that it would work with

```
is_dir('E:\DCIM\100NCD90\DSC_0007.JPG');
```

Comment: But it is not have drive letter, its portable device!

Comment: Again: you can't access a media device in PHP. But you can reconnect your device in **Mass Media** mode instead of MTP/PTP mode. In mass media mode it would become a drive letter. Check USB settings on your media device.

Comment: My device is Nikon camera, and I connected to my computer by USB, How can I check USB setting ?

Comment: Where I check USB setting ?
in my computer or in my Nikon camera ??

Comment: You should check it on your camera